# Error showing up on importing modal popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-bootstrap

Hi I am trying to import modal popup in react-bootstrap but it is showing the following error: Props not defined> I took it from react-bootstrap documents but am not able to understand the error

```
/src/components/AddProcessModal.js
  Line 24:28:  'props' is not defined  no-undef
```

Here is the code:

```
export class AddProcessModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        {...this.props}
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">Add KPI</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <div className="container">Add KPI Fields for BPMS</div>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
export default AddProcessModal;
```

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (preferably on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Comment: As this is a Class Component, you have to access props by this. For Example: this.props.onHide. I believe you must have passed onHide function from parent component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this part.

```
 <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
 </Modal.Footer>
```

It should be `this.props.onHide` instead of `props.onHide`.